# Android NativeActivity + other activity

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-activity

I have a native android application, then the entry main is android_main.
My question: Is possible generate another activity with the NativeActivity?
I must only insert the code java con android/src/com... and insert the class on androidmanifest.xml? Sorry, but I am new of the "android" world!

Comment: i think you are asking: Can i have more than one Activity..YES, the code goes somewhere in your package structure (basic Java!). You must have an entry in AndroidManifest.xml for each Activity.

Comment: do u mean to call a new activity from first activity , like going from page1 to page 2 ?????

Comment: So, I insert the my activity in java(src/com/myapp/) and on the manifest, and the android application, will execute alone the activity. But what application will stay up and which application will stand down? If I want insert abmod on my app, the admob activity must stay upper... (sorry for my bad English)

Comment: (i don't know anything about admob, sorry) Your main Activity will start when the user starts your app, any subsequent Activity that you decide to launch will "overlay" the previous Activity. I think  that AdMob will be seen at the TOP (or BOTTOM) of any Activity in your app (i assume you must leave room for it in the layout XML file)

Comment: means you want more than one activity for one xml file ?

Comment: I have create an second activity but it don't run... with the NDK I must launch with JNI?

Answer (score 1):

In the Android Developers page theres some theory about this feature, all is based on the Activity Stack and managing it, check 
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html , there are some descriptive images too.

Welcome to the Android world! :)

EDIT:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: I have created a activity in manifest.xml with android:launchMode="standard" and I have generated the java src... compiled... the new activity don't run. I have inserted a Log.i("MYTAG", "HERE!"), inside java src... but nothing. where I wrong?
first activity:
<activity android:name="android.app.NativeActivity"                     android:launchMode="standard"                         android:label="@string/app_name" [...]

second:
<activity android:launchMode="standard" android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"          android:configChanges="..."/>

Comment: I wonder you have 2 activities and you want to go from one to another, right?
If so, if you want to go to initiate activity B from activity A, you'll have to create an Intent in activity A, that is like a message to the system tell him to open the new activity.